# Mysql - multiple occurrences of strings between delimiters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the following results from a table that contains data in a mediumtext XML format.

I would like all occurrences of text between the opening delimiter, L7p:AuditDetailAssertion, and the next occurrence of closing delimiter /L7p:AuditDetailAssertion.

However, the difficult part is that there may be one or multiple occurrences of these strings.

This is how the XML shows up in the column when selecting it:

```
<wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
    <L7p:AuditAssertion>
        <L7p:SaveRequest booleanValue="true"/>
        <L7p:SaveResponse booleanValue="true"/>
    </L7p:AuditAssertion>
    <L7p:SetVariable>
        <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="doStatAudit"/>
    </L7p:SetVariable>
    <L7p:SetVariable>
        <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="doAudit"/>
    </L7p:SetVariable>
    <L7p:SetVariable>
        <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="auditOnFailure"/>
    </L7p:SetVariable>
    <L7p:SetVariable>
        <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="preRouteLatency"/>
    </L7p:SetVariable>
    <L7p:SslAssertion/>
    <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
        **<L7p:Detail stringValue="${request.http.allheadervalues}"/>
        <L7p:Enabled booleanValue="false"/>**
    </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
    <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
        <wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
            <wsse:SecurityToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd#UsernameToken</wsse:TokenType>
                <L7p:Properties/>
            </wsse:SecurityToken>
            <L7p:XpathCredentialSource>
                <L7p:Enabled booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:PasswordExpression xpathExpressionValue="included">
                    <L7p:Expression stringValue="/s:Envelope/s:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Password"/>
                    <L7p:Namespaces mapValue="included">
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="s"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="wsse"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                    </L7p:Namespaces>
                </L7p:PasswordExpression>
                <L7p:XpathExpression xpathExpressionValue="included">
                    <L7p:Expression stringValue="/S:Envelope/S:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:UsernameToken/wsse:Username"/>
                    <L7p:Namespaces mapValue="included">
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="ns2"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="/"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="s"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="S"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                        <L7p:entry>
                            <L7p:key stringValue="wsse"/>
                            <L7p:value stringValue="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
                        </L7p:entry>
                    </L7p:Namespaces>
                </L7p:XpathExpression>
            </L7p:XpathCredentialSource>
            <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
                **<L7p:Detail stringValue="${secpass.blah.plaintext}"/>**
            </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
            <L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
                <L7p:CaseSensitive booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:Expression1 stringValue="${request.username}"/>
                <L7p:Operator operatorNull="null"/>
                <L7p:Predicates predicates="included">
                    <L7p:item dataType="included">
                        <L7p:Type variableDataType="string"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                    <L7p:item binary="included">
                        <L7p:RightValue stringValue=""/>
                    </L7p:item>
                </L7p:Predicates>
            </L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
            <L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
                <L7p:CaseSensitive booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:Expression1 stringValue="${request.password}"/>
                <L7p:Operator operatorNull="null"/>
                <L7p:Predicates predicates="included">
                    <L7p:item dataType="included">
                        <L7p:Type variableDataType="string"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                    <L7p:item binary="included">
                        <L7p:RightValue stringValue="${secpass.AccountSearch.plaintext}"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                </L7p:Predicates>
            </L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
        </wsp:All>
        <wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
            <L7p:CustomizeErrorResponse>
                <L7p:Content stringValue="Forbidden!"/>
                <L7p:Enabled booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:ExtraHeaders nameValuePairArray="included"/>
                <L7p:HttpStatus stringValue="403"/>
            </L7p:CustomizeErrorResponse>
            <L7p:HardcodedResponse>
                <L7p:Base64ResponseBody stringValue=""/>
                <L7p:EarlyResponse booleanValue="true"/>
                <L7p:ResponseStatus stringValue="403"/>
            </L7p:HardcodedResponse>
            <L7p:SetVariable>
                <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
                <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="postRouteLatency"/>
            </L7p:SetVariable>
            <L7p:FalseAssertion/>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:OneOrMore>
    <L7p:HttpRoutingAssertion>
        <L7p:ConnectionTimeout stringValue="10000"/>
        <L7p:CurrentSecurityHeaderHandling intValue="3"/>
        <L7p:Login stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:PassThroughSoapFaults booleanValue="false"/>
        <L7p:Password stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:ProtectedServiceUrl stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:ProxyPassword stringValueNull="null"/>
        <L7p:ProxyUsername stringValueNull="null"/>
        <L7p:RequestHeaderRules httpPassthroughRuleSet="included">
            <L7p:Rules httpPassthroughRules="included">
                <L7p:item httpPassthroughRule="included">
                    <L7p:Name stringValue="Cookie"/>
                </L7p:item>
                <L7p:item httpPassthroughRule="included">
                    <L7p:Name stringValue="SOAPAction"/>
                </L7p:item>
            </L7p:Rules>
        </L7p:RequestHeaderRules>
        <L7p:RequestParamRules httpPassthroughRuleSet="included">
            <L7p:ForwardAll booleanValue="true"/>
            <L7p:Rules httpPassthroughRules="included"/>
        </L7p:RequestParamRules>
        <L7p:ResponseHeaderRules httpPassthroughRuleSet="included">
            <L7p:Rules httpPassthroughRules="included">
                <L7p:item httpPassthroughRule="included">
                    <L7p:Name stringValue="Set-Cookie"/>
                </L7p:item>
            </L7p:Rules>
        </L7p:ResponseHeaderRules>
    </L7p:HttpRoutingAssertion>
    <wsp:OneOrMore wsp:Usage="Required">
        <wsp:All wsp:Usage="Required">
            <L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
                <L7p:CaseSensitive booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:Expression1 stringValue="${auditOnFailure}"/>
                <L7p:Operator operatorNull="null"/>
                <L7p:Predicates predicates="included">
                    <L7p:item dataType="included">
                        <L7p:Type variableDataType="string"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                    <L7p:item binary="included">
                        <L7p:RightValue stringValue="true"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                </L7p:Predicates>
            </L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
            <L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
                <L7p:CaseSensitive booleanValue="false"/>
                <L7p:Expression1 stringValue="${response.http.status}"/>
                <L7p:Operator operatorNull="null"/>
                <L7p:Predicates predicates="included">
                    <L7p:item dataType="included">
                        <L7p:Type variableDataType="int"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                    <L7p:item binary="included">
                        <L7p:Operator operator="GE"/>
                        <L7p:RightValue stringValue="400"/>
                    </L7p:item>
                </L7p:Predicates>
            </L7p:ComparisonAssertion>
            <L7p:SetVariable>
                <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
                <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="doAudit"/>
            </L7p:SetVariable>
        </wsp:All>
        <L7p:TrueAssertion/>
    </wsp:OneOrMore>
         <L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
 <L7p:Detail stringValue="auditOnFailure: routingStatus: ${response.http.status}"/>
         </L7p:AuditDetailAssertion>
    <L7p:SetVariable>
        <L7p:Base64Expression stringValue=""/>
        <L7p:VariableToSet stringValue="postRouteLatency"/>
    </L7p:SetVariable>
</wsp:All>
```

Needed output:

```
L7p:Detail stringValue="${request.http.allheadervalues}"/
L7p:Detail stringValue="${secpass.blah.plaintext}"/
L7p:Enabled booleanValue="false"/
L7p:Detail stringValue="auditOnFailure: routingStatus: ${response.http.status}"/
```

Comment: And why exactly are you using this particular select query?

Comment: The question as stated above does not make sense. If you want only specific values, select only specific values. If you can't, you have a logical error. You should show the real table contents instead of a fake example from dual.

Comment: Can you post the SQL instruction you are using?

Comment: Edited with the real data...

Comment: Take a look to regular expresions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: how to account for multiple regular expressions within the same column?

Comment: this is a job for app code, not SQL. Retrieve the XML from the db, then do what you need in your app code. It could be done in sql, but just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should.